# Reading and Writing to file in resource folder Maven

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I am writing code for reading and writing file which is present in `src/main/resources` folder of Maven project, but code is reading and writing to file present in `"project/target/classes/config.properties"`, but what I need to read/write the file present in `"project/src/main/resources/config.properties"`. Below is a piece of code, I written:

```
public class PropertyFileReader {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(PropertyFileReader.class);

    private static Properties prop;

    static {
        prop = new Properties();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String property = read("config.properties", "number");
        System.out.println(property);
        write("config.properties", "number", "6");
    }

    public static String read(final String fileName, final String propertyName) {
        File file = getpropertyFile(fileName);
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while reading property from file : ",
                    ex);
        }
        return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
    }

    public static void write(final String fileName, final String propertName,
            String propertyValue) {
        File file = getpropertyFile(fileName);
        try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            prop.setProperty(propertName, propertyValue);
            prop.store(output, null);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while writing property to file : ",
                    io);
        }
    }

    private static File getpropertyFile(final String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = PropertyFileReader.class.getClassLoader();
        return new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
    }
}
```

I also read various posts related to it, which suggest to make some changes in pom.xml with adding `<RESOURCE_PATH>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</RESOURCE_PATH>`. But I am not understaning how should I do it.

Can you please guide me in implementing the same.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")` which gives you back a stream which can be used.

Comment: I tried it before also, it read from file placed at "project/src/main/resources/config.properties", that's fine but writing is still at file present at location "project/target/classes/config.properties".

Comment: You can't write a file from within a jar file into the jar file. If you need such things you need to define a different location where to store such files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit files within a jar file. Instead you can create temporary files from files within a jar file.

```
static File stream2file(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("stringOfYourChoice", ".tmp");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    Files.copy(in, tempFile.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING)
    return tempFile;
}
```